# SelectedIndexChange event not firing on dynamically created dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

I have a Telerik RadComboBox that when changed triggers some Javascript that uses AJAX to grab some data from the database and fills a second dropdownn lists with values. The problem is that I then want to fill some text boxes with data based upon the selection made in the second dropdownlist. The second dropdown list is a standard ASP.NET dropdownlist. Here is the code for the two dropdownlists:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbCustomer" runat="server" CssClass="form-control field-standard-size fix-background-white input-sm" width ="300px" Height="140px"
                        EmptyMessage="Type here to find sold-to customer" LoadingMessage="Please wait, loading..." AutoPostBack="true"
                        RegisterWithScriptManager="false" EnableEmbeddedScripts="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="rcbCustomer_IndexChanged">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>


<asp:DropDownList ID="hidShipTo" runat="server" Height="24px" Font-Size="x-small" CssClass="form-control input-sm width-300 form-fixer" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

When the first dropdown is changed it triggers this Javascript function which populates the second list:

```
function rcbCustomer_IndexChanged(sender, args) {

                //var strData = $("#<%=rcbCustomer.ClientID%>").val()
                var strComboID = $find("<%=rcbCustomer.ClientID%>");
                var strValue = strComboID.get_value();
                var strData = "{strCustomerSoldSelected: '" + strValue + "' }";
                //alert(strData);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/ProductServer.asmx/GetShipToData",
                    data: strData,
                    contentType: "application/json; character=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID %>").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("[-]").html("Please select"));
                        $.each(msg.d, function () {
                            $("#<%= hidShipTo.ClientID %>").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                        });
                    },
                    failure: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error1:" + xhr.status);
                        alert("Error2:" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
                //alert("the end");
            }
```

I am then binding the change event for the second dropdownlist as follows:

```
$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(hidShipTo_IndexChanged());
```

I then want it to run another function that uses AJAX to get the data to fill some other textboxes. Here is that function (right now it is set to just do an alert until I know it runs):

```
 function hidShipTo_IndexChanged(sender, args) {
                var strData = "";
                alert("yes");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/ProductServer.asmx/PopulateShipToDetails",
                    data: strData,
                    contentType: "application/json; character=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    failure: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error1:" + xhr.status);
                        alert("Error2:" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
```

The problem is that the change event doesn't seem to trigger. Any ideas on what could be the cause or maybe a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing from an ASP dropdownlist to a regular SELECT input control and the event bound properly and the code now runs properly. This was a conversion to eliminate postback refreshes, so I really didn't need the ASP dropdownlist. I am still really curious as to why the event wouldn't bind properly, but the problem is now solved. I wanted to post this in case anyone else has a similar problem. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling function not assigning it to event handler

change

```
$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(hidShipTo_IndexChanged()); //Remove ()
```

to

```
$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(hidShipTo_IndexChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the event still doesn't trigger

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning a function, you are calling it

```
$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(hidShipTo_IndexChanged());
                                                           ^^^
```

needs to be

```
$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(hidShipTo_IndexChanged);
                                                          ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, but making that change still does not trigger the event

Comment: Is the element there when you add the event? Are you actually selecting a different option in the list? Simple test: `console.log($("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").length);` Are you expecting the change event to fire when user changes or when the Ajax callback code changes the values?

Comment: Yes I have done a check on the length and it sees the selector. I am expecting the change event to fire when the user changes the dropdownlist. What I suspect is that because the original AJAX populated the dropdown there there is a problem because even though I can see 3 items in the dropdownlist, when I do a view source there is just <select> and </select> tags with no options because the options are added by the previous AJAX call. Any ideas?

Comment: View source NEVER shows updated html, you need to use the console and inspect the element.

Answer (score 0):

can you take a look how this server-side instruction is rendered on the client-side

```
    $("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(hidShipTo_IndexChanged());
```

Comment: It comes through like this:

`$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidShipTo").change(function () { hidShipTo_IndexChanged(); });`

Comment: Ok, the solution was given by satpal

Comment: No, that didn't cause the event to fire either.

Comment: did you verify if the clien side Id of your select tag is really ContentPlaceHolder1_hidShipTo ?

Comment: Is there any error in the javascript console of your browser ?

Comment: Yes, my first comment to this response is the exact code in the view source. There are no errors in the console at all.

Comment: May be because the instruction `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidShipTo").change(function () { hidShipTo_IndexChanged(); });` is never called at all. try to put it on `$(document).ready(function() { ...  });`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with that is to call it from unnamed function.

like this:

```
$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(function(){hidShipTo_IndexChanged();});
```

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions, but the bigger problem seems to be that the .change event is not firing at all. I wrote code like this:

`$("#<%=hidShipTo.ClientID%>").change(function(){alert('yes';});`

and nothing came up! What could cause that to not fire?

Comment: most of the times the event handler cannot bind to the event because it trying the be assigned when the element not there. in other words its very important that the DOM is ready before the binding happen.